# Existe algún problema en consumir un servicio web bajo https?

Tags: php, webservice, soap, https

estaba consumiendo un servicio web utilizando soap de la siguiente forma

```
$cliente_ = new nusoap_client("http://190.85.228.246/ws_repweb/ws_webrep.php");
```

La consulta se realizaba sin ningún problema hasta que se cambio la url por la siguiente:

```
$cliente_ = new nusoap_client("https://www.xxxxxxxxx.com.co/ws_repweb/ws_webrep.php");
```

Ahora al consumir el servicio no retorna nada, creo que ni siquiera realiza la petición... por eso la duda,

hay algún problema en utilizar un certificado https al comsumir un servicio web?
como puedo solucionar este inconveniente?

Agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Puede ser un problema con el certificado. Si vas a la URL desde navegador te regresa algo?

Comment: gracias por responder  @KacosPro   ,, al colocar la url en el navegador si regresa algo, específicamente lo que regresa son las diferentes consultas que contiene el servicio web... antes cuando la url no tenía certificado si funcionaba y el único cambio que se hizo fue implementarlo...

Comment: Según veo te regresa un `html`. Puede ser ese el problema? Intenta con la URL `https://www.xxxxxxx.xxx.co/ws_repweb/ws_webrep.php?wsdl`

Comment: @KacosPro  he colocado la url como lo has dicho pero no ha funcionado...